# Prove $\lim \int \vert f-f_n\vert d\mu=0 \iff \lim \int \vert f_n \vert d\mu=\int \vert f \vert d\mu$

Tags: measure-theory

$f_n$ and $f$ are real valued integrable functions and $f_n\xrightarrow{a.e.}f$.

My attempt on $\Rightarrow$: $\vert f_n-f\vert \geq \vert f_n\vert-\vert f \vert$ (and assume that this last one is greater then zero, otherwise we use $\vert f_n-f\vert \geq \vert f \vert - \vert f_n \vert$). Then just integrating and manipulating limits will lead us to what we want.

On $\Leftarrow$ I couldn't do anything =(

I couldn't use any theorem like LDCT or MCT because the hypothesis are just those above. So I got stucked...

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need assumption $\int |f| d\mu < \infty$.

We begin with the following claim:

> **Claim 1**: Let $\{g_n\}$ sequence of measurable functions, such that
>    1. $g_n \geq 0$
>    2. $g_n \to g$ a.e
>    3. $\int g d\mu < \infty$ and $\int g_n d\mu \to \int g d\mu$
>    **Then**
>   $\int |g_n -g| d\mu \to 0$

**Proof**:

Let $h_n = \min\{g_n, g\}$. We have $h_n \to g$ a.e, $0\leq h_n \leq g$.
By the dominated convergence theorem, we have $\int h_n d\mu \to \int g d\mu$.
In other hand, we have $$h_n = \frac{(g_n + g -|g_n -g|)}{2}\text{ or }|g_n -g| = 2h_n -g_n -g$$ 
Hence the claim is proved.

---

By the claim, we have $|f_n| \to |f|$ in $L^1$.

Let $g_n = (|f_n| + f_n)/2$, we have $g_n \geq 0$, $g_n \to (|f| + f)/2$ and $g_n \leq |f_n|$.
By Fatou's lemma, we have
$$\liminf \int g_n d\mu \geq \int \frac{|f| +f}2 d\mu.$$
In other hand, $|f_n| -g_n = (|f_n| -f_n) / 2 \geq 0$, hence by Fatou's lemma again, we have
$$\liminf \int (|f_n| -g_n) d\mu \geq \int (|f| - \frac{|f| +f}2) d\mu.$$
Since $\int |f_n| d\mu \to \int |f| d\mu$, hence
$$\liminf \int (|f_n| -g_n) d\mu = \liminf (\int |f_n| d\mu - \int g_n d\mu) = \liminf \int |f_n| d\mu + \liminf (-\int g_n d\mu) = \int |f| d\mu -\limsup \int g_n d\mu.$$
Hence 
$$\limsup \int g_n d\mu \leq \int \frac{|f| +f}2 d\mu.$$
Therefore, we have $\int g_n d\mu \to \int \frac{|f| +f}2 d\mu$.
By the claim, we have $g_n \to (|f|+f)/2$ in $L^1$.
Hence $f_n = 2g_n - |f_n| \to 2 \frac{|f| +f}2 -|f| =f$ in $L^1$.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that $L^1$ is a normed space, then by continuity of the norm you obtain that $\Vert f-f_n\Vert_{L^1}\rightarrow 0$ implies that $\Vert f_n\Vert_{L^1}\rightarrow \Vert f\Vert_{L^1}$.

For the other direction, Fatou's lemma is useful with a certain choice of funtions. Specifically define $g_n:=\frac{1}{2}\Big( \vert f\vert +\vert f_n\vert \Big)-\frac{1}{2}\vert f_n-f\vert$.
By the triangle inequality these functions are non-negative. Since $f_n\rightarrow f$ almost everywhere you can see that:

$\frac{1}{2}\Big( \vert f\vert +\vert f_n\vert \Big)\overset{a.e}{\rightarrow}\vert f\vert$ and $\vert f_n-f\vert\overset{a.e}{\rightarrow}0$, which implies that $g_n\overset{a.e}{\rightarrow}\vert f\vert$.

Using Fatou's lemma we can conclude:

$ (*) \int \vert f\vert d\mu= \int\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\liminf}(g_n)d\mu \leq \underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\liminf} \int g_n d\mu$

Then:

$\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\liminf} \int g_n d\mu \leq \underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\liminf} \Big( \frac{1}{2}\int \vert f\vert d\mu +\frac{1}{2}\int \vert f_n\vert d\mu \Big)-\frac{1}{2}\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\limsup} \int \vert f_n-f\vert d\mu= $

$=\frac{1}{2}\int \vert f\vert d\mu+ \frac{1}{2}\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\liminf}\int \vert f_n\vert d\mu-\frac{1}{2}\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\limsup} \int \vert f_n-f\vert d\mu=$

$\overset{\int \vert f_n\vert d\mu \rightarrow \int \vert f\vert d\mu}{=} \int \vert f\vert d\mu-\frac{1}{2}\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\limsup} \int \vert f_n-f\vert d\mu$

Then from (*) we conclude that:

$\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\limsup} \int \vert f_n-f\vert d\mu = 0$, which implies that $\int \vert f_n-f\vert d\mu \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Very nice! Just for being sure... did you mean $g_n=\frac{1}{2}(\vert f\vert+\vert f_n\vert - \vert f_n-f\vert)?$

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure I meant as defined above. Though looking at the proof now you could multiply $\vert f_n-f \vert$ by any $0<c<1$ and the proof would  still work.

Comment: Yes, it still works... but I thought it was this way because I just can conclude $g_n\geq 0$ with $g_n$ like this... and the minus signal for $\lim\inf -x$ becoming $-\lim\sup x$

Comment: Now that I think about it you're probably write, I'll edit it. By what I wrote, verbally about the triangle inequality this seems like what is needed. Though I tend to get mixed up with constants.

Comment: hmm wait.. you used $\lim \inf (a_n+b_n)\leq \lim \inf a_n + \lim \inf b_n$... isn't $\geq$ ?

Comment: I didn't use it actually, I used the reverse inequality